# Fixing / Backing up phone that doesn't get recognized by pc and is stuck in a boot loop

Tags: adb, boot-loop, fastboot, oneplus-one

I currently have a OnePlus One, which since this morning seems to have broken, it's permanently stuck in a boot loop where it shows the OPO logo, but stays there until the battery runs out.

I want to make a back-up and re-install the firmware, however my PC doesn't recognize it when running `adb devices` or `fastboot devices`. I'm sure I have the drivers installed on my PC (which the original download links are now all dead by the way), as I've connected my phone before.

Does anyone know how I could either:

- Transfer my files to my PC
- Get my PC to recognize my phone

I looked in the following locations for help:

- https://blog.gluegarage.com/?p=244
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJnoiMTw5cY
- https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/
- https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/computer-doesnt-see-phone-while-in-fastboot-mode.279660/page-2
- https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/oneplus-one-how-to-unlock-bootloader-install-custom-recovery-and-root.64487/

Comment: Can you enter in the recovery mode?

Comment: @JoseLuisMontañes I was able to, but it's completely bricked now, won't even turn on. Thanks though